# vuejs v-for with file objects wont work

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I try to make a list using `v-for`, but it seems like I cant use `v-bind:class` on the file objects list, but it works on the normal objects.

My code so far:

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    files: [],
    objects: [
     { status: 'added' }
    ]
  },
  
  mounted() {
   var f = new File([""], "filename");
    this.files.push(this.extend(f, { status: 'added' }));
    
    // This one is working
    console.log(this.objects);
    
    // This one is not working
    console.log(this.files);
  },
  
  methods: {
    startUpload: function (file) {
      this.$set(file, 'status', 'uploading');
    },
    
    uploadObject: function (object) {
     this.$set(object, 'status', 'uploading');
    },
    
    extend: function(obj, src) {
     Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
    return obj;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

li > span.uploading {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="file in files">
      <span v-bind:class="{ uploading: file.status == 'uploading' }">File status: {{ file.status }}</span> <a href="#" v-on:click="startUpload(file)">upload</a>
    </li>  
  </ul>
  
  ----
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="object in objects">
      <span v-bind:class="{ uploading: object.status == 'uploading' }">Object status: {{ object.status }}</span> <a href="#" v-on:click="uploadObject(object)">upload</a>
    </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue doesnt update view after you change property of **File**. So you can just force it. Like this

```
this.$set(file, 'status', 'uploading');    
this.$forceUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood the essence of the question, do you want to assign the required class ('upload') based on the status?

```
<span v-bind:class="object.status == 'uploading' ? 'uploading' : ''">Object status: {{ object.status }}</span> <a href="#" v-on:click="uploadObject(object)">upload</a>
```

Comment: Yes, object.status works just fine, but the file.status don't.

Comment: pls, write that output console.log(this.files);